# Столбец по сгруппированным данным Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Имеется Pandas DataFrame, например:

```
  city  col1  
0  nsk    15
1  nsk    17
2  nsk    22
3  vdk    11
4  vdk     9
```

Требуется добавить столбец, в котором будут суммы значений `col1`, сгруппированные по столбцу `city`. Например:

```
  city  col1  col2
0  nsk    15    54
1  nsk    17    54
2  nsk    22    54
3  vdk    11    20
4  vdk     9    20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [434]: df['col2'] = df.groupby('city')['col1'].transform('sum')

In [435]: df
Out[435]:
  city  col1  col2
0  nsk    15    54
1  nsk    17    54
2  nsk    22    54
3  vdk    11    20
4  vdk     9    20
```